# Linking to a static library with a makefile and g++

Tags: c++, makefile, g++

I want to link my C++ executable to both a static (`libStatic.a`) and a shared (`libShared.so`) library, using a makefile.

The makefile so far has the following content:

```
myExe: main.cpp libStatic.a libShared.so
    g++ main.cpp libStatic.a libShared.so
```

I'm fairly sure that the static linking is correct, as I have seen similar things elsewhere. What I am unsure of is the shared linking part. Is this correct? Or is linking to a static library done differently?

If I run make, then it seems to be ok, and creates the executable. However, when I execute this, I reveive the error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lShared
```

However, my executable and `libShared.so` are in the same directory.

Comment: Partially -- it compiles and links ok, but it cannot load the shared library at runtime...

Comment: Then I'd say the answer is "no, it's not correct".

Comment: Ok...any idea what I should be doing instead?

Comment: The likelihood is that this has nothing to do with the static library. Why don't you try one at a time before you try using both at once?

Comment: Use `g++ main.cpp libStatic.a libShared.so -Wl,-rpath,.`

Comment: @skwllsp feel free to edit that into my answer :-)

Comment: Ew no don't do that either

Comment: OK, The better way is `g++ main.cpp libStatic.a libShared.so -Wl,-rpath,$ORIGIN`. It is much better. It make ld.so looks for a shared library in the same dir where myExe is. It is about "turn-key" applications http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `LD_LIBARY_PATH` to this directory where the shared object is sitting before you run your program.

You can read up on 'rpath' in `man ld` for other possibilities.

Comment: I thought that the operating system automatically looks in the directory of the executable, to see if the shared library is in there?

Comment: Nope. Not on Linux, never.

Comment: But only do this for testing. Not in deployment.

Comment: @Karnivaurus: No. On Linux there are standard library search paths, but the directory of the executable is not one of them. Not for dynamic linking. (I think it does on Windows)

Comment: Ah, ok thanks. I think I'm used to Windows where I seem to remember it does search the executable directory...